# Java Script Function not returning value from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following AJax request function which is working fine. upon successful it returns 1 else 2.

Now i would like to perform some action outside of this function based on this return value, as below, but its not working .. it always returns "**undefined**"...

I expect the `return_code` should return either `1 or 2` based on following code

```
<script>

var return_code=add_to_cart_ajax(200);
alert(return_code);
</script>
returns "undefined"
```

**AJAX Request :**

```
<script>
//Ajax to send request to add 
function add_to_cart_ajax(id)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // returns 1 
                if (xmlhttp.responseText==1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
          }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","add.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}//end of the function..
</script>
```

Comment: change the return to an alter(1) / alert(2)

Comment: @ManuelRicharz : i already said, alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // returns 1

Comment: great. ajax is an asycn task. if you write a script code and expect a return value from this method, it will not work.

Comment: @ManuelRicharz : So please tell me some alternate solution

Comment: onreadystatechange is a event. you have to wait this event gets fired

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Shomz : I expect the `return_code` should return either `1 or 2` based on following code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an AJAX call is asynchronous one common way of dealing with it is to use a callback-function that gets called once the request is processed.

Something like

```
<script>
  add_to_cart_ajax(200, function(return_code) {
     alert(return_code);
  });
</script>


<script>
  //Ajax to send request to add 
  function add_to_cart_ajax(id, callback) {

    ...

    alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // returns 1 
    if (xmlhttp.responseText==1) {
      callback(1);
    } else {
      callback(2);
    }

    ...        

  }//end of the function..
</script>
```

EDIT: If you need to hang on to the return_code, you'd do

```
<script>
  var return_code;
  add_to_cart_ajax(200, function(result) {
     return_code = result;
  });
</script>
```

But it's important to understand that since the AJAX request is asynchronous, your `return_code` variable will not have a value assigned to it untill the AJAX request is fulfilled and you can't use it for anything untill that has happened, so any code that needs to do something with `return_code` should be included in or called from the callback. This is one of the things that is going to be a bit hard to grasp at first if you're coming from a background where all code is being run top-to-down. That's simply not the case once you start working with asynchronous stuff.

Comment: what does callback(1) mean ? there is no function defined for callback

Comment: `function add_to_cart_ajax(id, callback)` dictates that the `add_to_cart_ajax` function takes an argument that is the `callback`. It then calls that function once the request is completed. If you look at the top code-block you'll see that this is passed in after the `id` of 200.

Comment: You can read more about callbacks here: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: Once you have a good grip on callbacks, I also suggest looking into `promises`, which often tends to be a cleaner way of handling asynchronous code.

Comment: can i do like this ? i need to store the return code. `var return_code= add_to_cart_ajax(200, function(return_code) {
     return 1;
  });`

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer.

Comment: okay. then my code wont work ?

Comment: No, the way you posted it in the original question, it will never work because it does not handle the asynchronous nature of an AJAX request. I strongly suggest reading up on asynchronous programming because it is a concept that you need to understand if you're going to do any kind of browser-server communication with Javascript.

Comment: Also,if i call `add_to_cart_ajax(id, callback)` multiple times in another loop its not working... works for only last loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that an ajax call is async, you can't expect to have the result in your `alert(return_code);` because effectively at that time the ajax call has not get the response yet.

Could be useful to give a look at how libraries as jQuery or Zepto have done as well as implementing something following "promise" logic, just to avoid the callback hell.

Comment: I havent used JQuery for ages now, did they finally get around to using promises for `$.ajax`?

Comment: I hardly use it but they implements promises/deferred logic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

ok i will try to make an example:

if you order a package on amazon and you want to unpack this in the next step

```
orderPackage();
unpackPackage(); // undefined / exception, because you have to wait for the package to be arrived
```

try not to return a value with the "onreadystatechange". you can call another function from inside this method or you can set global variables. as example:

**Just to explain how ajax works (DO NOT USE THIS PEACE OF CODE, SCROLL DOWN FOR BETTER SOLUTION!):**

```
ajaxReturn = null;

function add_to_cart_ajax(id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                ajaxReturn = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","add.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    while(ajaxReturn == null) {
    //waiting for response
    //will break if the request is finished
    }

    alert(ajaxReturn);

}//end of the function..
```

**Please not use this in productive** because the while will cause the browser to stop i think.
but this should explain the behaviour to you.

**Right Solutions**

```
// This will send an ajax-request and execute the fCallback if finished
// @param sUrl - Url to send the request to
// @param fCallbackSuccess - method that will be executed on successfull request
// @param fCallbackFailed - method that will be executed on failed request
// @param bAsync - will make the request async or sync
function ajax(sUrl, fCallbackSuccess, fCallbackFailed, bAsync) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          oXmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          oXmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        oXmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
           if (oXmlHttp.readyState==4 && oXmlHttp.status==200) {
                fCallbackSuccess.apply(oXmlHttp);
                return;
           }
           fCallbackFailed.apply(oXmlHttp);
        }
        oXmlHttp.open("GET", sUrl, bAsync);
        oXmlHttp.send();
}

//usage example:

var fSuccess = function(oXmlHttp) {
   //do something with oXmlHttp
   alert(oXmlHttp.responseText);
}

var fFailed= function(oXmlHttp) {
   //do something with oXmlHttp
   alert('Request failed!');
}

ajax("add.php?id="+id, fSuccess, fFailed, true);
```

have a nice day

Comment: downvote? greate i can live with that... but please explain also for others. use the commentbox for that. thanks

Comment: if you read my post carefully..... you will see.

Comment: the problem in the main question is not the return of 1 or 2. the problem is the understanding of async ajax. and this is what i want to explain in my post. yes of course callbacks are the better solution. but in the first step he has to understand how it works.

Comment: ok let me do some changes.

Comment: I am not seeing any down vote ! what do you mean by oXmlHttp ? and whats the difference between oXmlHttp and xmlHttp ?

Comment: no difference between oXmlHttp and xmlHttp! it is just a different naming convention. i name every variable by its type: f = function, b = boolean, o = object, i = integer and so on. so anybody know what's inside this variable.